# how to refresh JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm making a simple program that show the teams, the matches and racking goal of Euro2016 in France.
I have some problem with JTable when changing query.
Here is what happens:

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/kcxe1c.png]

[image]

when I change from a Table of (for example) 10 rows to another one that contains only 5 rows it works. But if I change from a table that contains 5 rows to another of 10, the table doesn't change, it displays only 5 rows.
Here the code:

```
public class Euro2016GUI extends JFrame {

private Container container;
private Sfondo pnlSfondo;
JTable table;
JPanel panel;

static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
static Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();

public Euro2016GUI() {
    data.removeAll(data);
    headers.removeAll(headers);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setSize(600, 400);
    this.setTitle("Euro2016");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pnlSfondo = new Sfondo();

    container = this.getContentPane();
    container.add(pnlSfondo);
}

public void createTable(String pQuery) {
    data.removeAll(data);
    headers.removeAll(headers);

    Control control = new Control();

    panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setSize(300, 300);
    panel.setBackground(Color.red);

    control.getData(pQuery);
    data = control.getData();
    headers = control.getHeaders();

    //this is the model which contain actual body of JTable
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);

    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setEnabled(false);
    table.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 300));

    header_size();

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    //scroll.setSize(600, 400);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void header_size() {
    int colonne = table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();
    TableColumn column;

    for (int i = 0; i < colonne; i++) {
        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        column.setPreferredWidth(200);
    }
}

public void cleanData() {

    if (table != null) {
        DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        dm.setRowCount(0);
        table.revalidate();
    }
    data.removeAll(data);
    headers.removeAll(headers);
   }
}
```

CLASS CONTROL

```
public class Control {

private static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
private static Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();

public void getData(String pQuery) {

    // Enter Your MySQL Database Table name in below Select Query.
    String query = pQuery;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    Statement st = null;
    int colonne = 0;

    data.removeAll(data);
    headers.removeAll(headers);

    try {
        con = DBConnectionPool.getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();

        rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        colonne = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= colonne; i++) {
            headers.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<String> d = new Vector<String>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= colonne; i++) {
                d.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(d);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (st != null) {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DataInJTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            DBConnectionPool.releaseConnection(con);
        }
    }
}

public Vector<Vector<String>> getData() {
    return this.data;
}

public Vector<String> getHeaders() {
    return this.headers;
}
```

}

HERE THE ACTION LISTENER IN THE MENU:

```
...
 //----ROSE---//
 private class OnClickRose implements ActionListener {

    Sfondo sfondo;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = e.getActionCommand();
        str = str.replace("[", "");
        str = str.replace("]", "");

        String sx = "'";
        String dx = "'";
        String query = query2.concat(sx.concat(str.concat(dx)));
        //frame.cleanData();

        sfondo = frame.getPnlSfondo();
        if (sfondo.isVisible() && sfondo.getParent().isVisible()) {
            sfondo.setVisible(false);
        }

        frame.createTable(query);
    }
}

 //----CALENDARIO----//
private class OnClickCalendario implements ActionListener {

    Sfondo sfondo;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        frame.cleanData();
        sfondo = frame.getPnlSfondo();

        if (sfondo.isVisible() && sfondo.getParent().isVisible()) {
            sfondo.setVisible(false);
        }

        frame.createTable(query4);
    }
}

//----CLASSIFICA MARCATORI----//
private class OnClickMarcatori implements ActionListener {

    Sfondo sfondo;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        frame.cleanData();
        sfondo = frame.getPnlSfondo();

        if (sfondo.isVisible() && sfondo.getParent().isVisible()) {
            sfondo.setVisible(false);
        }

        frame.createTable(query3);
    }
}
...
```

Could anybody tell me where I wrong?

Comment: First, there should not be a need to re-create the JTable. Simply create a single instance and change its TableModel, it will do the rest

Comment: Second, your continuously add JTables to the contentPane, but don't seem to ever remove anything from it, this is going to cause issues as the previous components are still visible...

Comment: I noticed I create a new JPanel each time I click on a menu, the problem was that the old panel were still on display, so I decided to set the visibility of the panel on "false" when I execute a new query ( when I go from a menu to another). It seem it works, even if in a brutal way. I'll keep in mind your advices and I'll try as soon as possible to improve my code. I'll let you know, thank you :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score -1):

Basically to tell the table to refresh itself, you just call the method fireTableDataChanged() of it's table model.
So in your example, after you run the query, you could just call:

```
((DefaultTableModel)yourTable.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
```

But I suggest you to stop using default table model, and implement your own table model. It's a lot easier to work.

Comment: No, you should never need to call any of the TableModel fireXxx methods from outside the TableModel. If the data is updated correctly, the model will trigger the required events by itself

Comment: This answer goes from bad to worse. If you're trying to solve problems with a table, ignore it completely.